# How can i access my array inside of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a object and inside of object hava data array. But i cant access it. When i log my object i can see my data inside like that : https://ibb.co/mJfHnhq

But when i try write like objectname.data its show empty array like : https://ibb.co/yNSDb94
How can i call it for access my data. I need send it to component but when i send objectname.data its sending empty array. Thanks for reply!

Its How i fill my object data :

```
const [myData,setMyData]=useState(DropdownElements); //Dropdown elements holds my url title empty array data for fill  etc.
const [myDatax,setMyDatax]=useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  myData.map((x, i) => {
      fetch(x.apiUrl)
      .then((z) => z.json())
      .then((result) => {
         myData[i].data = result;
         setMyData(myData);
       });
    });
}, []);
```

Its where i try use it but when i write x.data i cant see my data

```
return (
    <div>
           
           {myData.map(x=>{
             console.log('MYDATA',x.data)
             
          
            
             return (
               <MySpecialPicker
               key={x.key}
               placeholder={x.placeholder}
               onChange={change=>onchange(change)}
               datasource={x.data}
               >
    
    
               </MySpecialPicker>
             )
           })}
        </div>
       
      )
    }
```

Comment: I think because of the synchronization issue.

Comment: @decpk im sorry brother i asking coz i dont know it. How can i show my log without image ?

Comment: Probably related: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: It would be better to understand if you could add some code...

Comment: To analyze the issues, you should add some code how to set data in array.

Comment: Please do try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to examine. It's very difficult to help debug code we can't see.

Comment: @decpk I edit brother.

Comment: @GretchenRichards I add some codes how i set it and how i try call it

Comment: @DrewReese i edit brother sorry.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are mutating your state object. When you enqueue a bunch of state updates within a loop using non-functional updates they all use the state from the render cycle the updates were enqueued in, not the value of any previously updated state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  myData.map((x, i) => {
      fetch(x.apiUrl)
      .then((z) => z.json())
      .then((result) => {
         myData[i].data = result; // <-- mutation, myData state from previous render
         setMyData(myData);
       });
    });
}, []);
```

## Solution

Use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state instead of the state that was closed over in callback scope when the effect ran. Use `.forEach` since you are issuing a side-effect to fetch data, not map to a new array (*just yet*).

```
useEffect(() => {
  myData.forEach((x, i) => {
      fetch(x.apiUrl)
      .then((z) => z.json())
      .then((result) => {
         setMyData(myData => myData.map((el, index) => index === i {
           ...el,
           data: result,
         } : el));
       });
    });
}, []);
```

Or map an array of fetch requests and Promise.all them and update state once.

```
useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all(myData.map(x => fetch(x.apiUrl).then((z) => z.json())))
    .then(data => {
      setMyData(myData => myData.map((el, i) => ({
        ...el,
        data: data[i]
      })));
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was here :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  myData.map((x, i) => {
      fetch(x.apiUrl)
      .then((z) => z.json())
      .then((result) => {
         myData[i].data = result;
         setMyData(myData);
       });
    });
}, []);
```

In my opinion it is normal that you do not find data because those are promises you are returning a value before the promise value obtained, I advise you to use ES6 or higher with `async / await` it more easy.

Somethink like :

```js
await Promise.all(
  myData.map(async(x, i) => {
    const z = await fetch(x.apiUrl);

    const result = z.json(); // this is to be checked

    myData[i].data = result;
    setMyData(myData);
  });
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply brother but in useeffect can i use async await or what ? where should i use it

Comment: I have updated the code so that it allows you to see better what it looks like.

Comment: Thank you! But its still same brother. i still cant see it. And your code gives me promise but i used async await on my code as yours but still same issue

Comment: It would be necessary to adapt my example with your code because I do not know exactly all the code. But normally `async/await` should fix the problem because it does` asynchronous` as well as `synchronous`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` callbacks should be synchronous. `fetch` returns a Promise, the promise chain will work in a synchronous callback function. Even if the `async` callback worked you'd still have the issue of state mutation and updates stomping on any previous state update.

Comment: Can you please console log the value of `result` and `z` to see what it returns?

Comment: @DrewReese is right I forgetten `await Promise.all(...)`. updated the code.

Comment: But don't forget to put a console log of the `result` and `z` values ​​to see if they contain anything

Comment: @Sega I actually copy-paste your code but still same brother i cant understanding it

Comment: You can see documentation in [Promise docs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining)